What is the correct answer and reasoning to this question?
I stumbled upon this question while reviewing for the SAT:

Jetties—long, narrow structures that extend from a landmass into the water—are often constructed to protect coastlines from erosion. Jetties can sometimes have the opposite ________ obstructing the natural flow of sand along the shore can lead to increased erosion in some areas.
Which choice completes the text so that it conforms to the conventions of Standard English?
A. effect, though,
B. effect, though;
C. effect, though
D. effect; though

The correct answer provided was A. effect, though and I cannot wrap my head around this. I also have trouble identifying the word's grammatical role in this sentence.

The grammatical role of what word?

Welcome to ELU. As it’s now formed, your question is not clear enough for us to provide any answer with confidence. What is it exactly that you “cannot wrap your head around”? And what about it do you find so puzzling? And what efforts have you made to resolve this on your own? All these things are important in helping others give answers that may be as useful to you as possible, so I encourage you to edit your post to clarify these points.

You might want to consider the variants << ... Jetties can sometimes have the opposite effect, though. Obstructing the natural flow of sand along the shore can lead to increased erosion in some areas. >> and << ... Jetties can sometimes have the opposite effect, though: obstructing the natural flow of sand along the shore can lead to increased erosion in some areas. >> Few would consider A the correct answer.

You should also rewrite your question. The answer A. effect, though, is what you are having trouble with. You put it down as A. effect, though which is not the same.

B is correct...


I also have trouble identifying the word's grammatical role in this sentence.

You haven't provided which word you mean, so I cannot answer that part of your question.
It seems to me that the correct answer would be B, 'effect, though;' and not A, 'effect, though,'.

Jetties ... are often constructed to protect coastlines from erosion.¹ Jetties can sometimes have the opposite [________]² obstructing the natural flow of sand along the shore can lead to increased erosion in some areas.³

In the second sentence, we introduce a statement contrasting with that of the first sentence (they are constructed to protect—but—they sometimes damage), so we use the adverb 'though' to emphasise that contrast. Folwing that is the third sentence, which explains how they have the opposite effect. It is an independent clause, which means it has all the needed syntactic elements for it to be able to stand without any other clauses supporting it (i.e., it has a subject, a verb, and any other arguments the verb requires).
The third sentence is independent

Obstructing the natural flow of sand along the shore can lead to increased erosion in some areas.

Subject: 'Obstructing the natural flow of sand along the shore'
Verb phrase: 'can lead'
Verb complement: 'to increased erosion in some areas'
The second sentence is likewise independent

Jetties can sometimes have the opposite effect, though

Subject: 'Jetties'
Verb phrase: 'can sometimes have'
Verb complement: 'the opposite effect'
Whenever two independent clauses are linked, one of three things can be used: 1. a full-stop, 2. a semicolon, and 3. a coordinating conjunction with a comma preceding it. When a comma is used, that is a comma splice. It's a very common mistake and often done in casual, informal English.
Option A, 'effect, though,' constitutes a comma splice, as it employs a comma to link two independent clauses.
Option C, 'effect, though', on the other hand, constitutes a fused sentence (a much greater sin). Fused sentences occur when independent clauses are joined with no punctuation at all in between.
Option D, 'effect; though', places the 'though' at the start of the third sentence, which sets up the expectation of a contrast further down the sentence, yet no such contrast is provided.
Thus, via a process of elimination, we can determine that option B, 'effect, though;' is the only correct one. Indeed, a semicolon or full stop would work in that position, as the two clauses are independent.

There's nothing wrong with a comma splice according to many authorities (check out the questions here), but certainly B is fine.
